# convert MySQL SQL to work in MS-Access Database

Tags: sql, ms-access

Trying to convert this working SQL from MySql database to work on a MS Access database:

```
    SELECT u.LastName AS LAST, u.FirstName AS FIRST,
    MAX(IF(`e.ClassName`='MDC (Intro)', DateCompleted, NULL)) AS 'MDC', 
    MAX(IF(`e.ClassName`='800 MHz Radio (Intro)', DateCompleted, NULL)) AS 'RADIO',
    MAX(IF(`e.ClassName`='ePCR (Intro)', DateCompleted, NULL)) AS 'ePCR',
    MAX(IF(`e.ClassName`='Firehouse (Incident)', DateCompleted, NULL)) AS 'Firehouse'
    FROM EnrollmentsTbl e INNER JOIN UsersDataTbl u ON e.UserName = u.UserName
    GROUP BY e.UserName 
    WHERE u.LastName LIKE 'Bar%' 
    ORDER BY u.LastName
```

Comment: @SqlZim: Your SQL should work except for `WHERE u.LastName LIKE 'Bar*'`.

Comment: it's not working - how does Access work with ``e.ClassName``?

Comment: Your 'IF' needs to be 'IIF'   Also, I was surprised that you could use `around the table/field references, but I learned something new... the day is a success!

Comment: I have changed that, and enclosed `[e.ClassName]` and still no go...

Comment: There is no need to bracket `e.Classname` - and if, it should be: `[e].[Classname]`. But you may need _AS_: `FROM EnrollmentsTbl AS e INNER JOIN UsersDataTbl AS u`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if its aligned exactly as I want it (need first/last in the first column, and the `GROUP BY` was the main problem, but this returns results from Access:

```
SELECT u.LastName AS [LAST], 
Max(IIf([e.ClassName]='MDC (Intro)',Format([DateCompleted],'mm/dd/yyyy'),Null)) AS [MDC], 
Max(IIf([e.ClassName]='800 MHz Radio (Intro)',Format([DateCompleted],'mm/dd/yyyy'),Null)) AS [RADIO], 
Max(IIf([e.ClassName]='ePCR (Intro)',Format([DateCompleted],'mm/dd/yyyy'),Null)) AS [ePCR], 
Max(IIf([e.ClassName]='Firehouse (Incident)',Format([DateCompleted],'mm/dd/yyyy'),Null)) AS [Firehouse]
FROM EnrollmentsTbl e 
INNER JOIN UsersDataTbl u ON e.UserName = u.UserName
GROUP BY u.LastName, u.FirstName, e.UserName
WHERE u.UserName LIKE 'bar%' 
ORDER BY u.LastName;
```

Comment: actually I'll update the answer - all those work fine. it seemed to need the `[LAST]` and `[ClassName]`

Comment: Main issue is the `GROUP BY ` clause requiring *FirstName* and *LastName*. See my edit above.

Comment: yep - just had a typo in your as well `ALIKE`

Answer (score 1):

A few items of syntax requires conversion:

1. A very important item and one unfortunately MySQL users tend to abuse (which run with [only full group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode off). In SQL, `GROUP BY` must include ALL non-aggregated columns. So add `FirstName` and `LastName` to the grouping.
2. MS Access SQL does not use `IF` for conditional expressions but `IIF()`.
3. While Access does use backticks and square brackets, it can only be used to enclose column names and/or table names not both together. Come to think of it MySQL allows backticks around column and/or table names but not both in same enclosure pair (just checked in MySQL 5.5).
4. Access does not identify column aliases with any single or double quote which the latter is the ANSI standard. Interestingly, you can include quotes but they will show up literally in column name. MySQL adheres to ANSI double quote for object identifiers with [ANSI-Quotes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) sql mode on.
5. Finally, Access via ODBC does use `%` wildcard for `LIKE` evaluation but Access via the GUI .exe program uses `*` by default. But its `ALIKE` operator is valid in both setup types.

Consider the following SQL adjustment:

```
SELECT u.LastName AS `LAST`, u.FirstName AS `FIRST`,
       MAX(IIF(e.`ClassName`='MDC (Intro)', DateCompleted, NULL)) AS `MDC`, 
       MAX(IIF(e.`ClassName`='800 MHz Radio (Intro)', DateCompleted, NULL)) AS `RADIO`,
       MAX(IIF(e.`ClassName`='ePCR (Intro)', DateCompleted, NULL)) AS `ePCR`,
       MAX(IIF(e.`ClassName`='Firehouse (Incident)', DateCompleted, NULL)) AS `Firehouse`
FROM EnrollmentsTbl e 
INNER JOIN UsersDataTbl u ON e.UserName = u.UserName
GROUP BY u.LastName, u.FirstName, e.UserName 
WHERE u.LastName ALIKE 'Bar%' 
ORDER BY u.LastName
```

Comment: your example uses `e.```ClassName``` but not in `u.LastName` - should this rule apply to all?

Comment: See update. I added the `GROUP BY` syntax needs. Sorry for the earlier  overlook! And backticks are optional, usually only to escape reserved words and names with spaces/special chars.